# Переключение радио кнопок по нажатию на обычные кнопки

Tags: javascript, jquery

столкнулся с проблемой. Как сделать, чтобы при нажатии на обычные кнопки можно было переключать радио кнопки. Каждая из обычных кнопок привязана к радио через data-атрибут.

```js
const btn = '.radio__label';

$(btn).on('click', function() {
  $($(this).attr('data-rad')).prop('checked', true);
});
```

```css
.radio-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.button-wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-wrapper">
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio1">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio2">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio3">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD3</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio4">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD4</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio1">
    RAD1
  </button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio2">
    RAD2
  </button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio3">
    RAD3
  </button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio4">
    RAD4
  </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
// при нажатии на любой из button, значение data-rad которого начинается с radio
$('button[data-rad^="radio"]').on('click', function() {
  $('input[data-rad=' + $(this).data('rad') + ']').prop('checked', true);
});
```

```css
.radio-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.button-wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-wrapper">
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio1">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio2">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio3">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD3</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio4">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD4</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio1">RAD1</button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio2">RAD2</button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio3">RAD3</button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio4">RAD4</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Хороший ответ +1) Прокомментируйте пожалуйста это `^=`.

Comment: @doox911 + коммент в ответе

Answer (score 1):

Значение `data-*` в `button` и `input` должны совпадать.

```js
const btn = '.radio__label';

$(btn).on('click', function() {
  $($(this).attr('data-rad')).prop('checked', true);
});

$('.button-wrapper button').on('click', function(){
  const data = $(this).data('rad');
  $('input.radio__input').each(function(){
    if($(this).data('rad') === data){
      $(this).prop('checked', true);
    } else {
      $(this).prop('checked', false);
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.radio-wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
}

.button-wrapper {
  margin-top: 30px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  justify-content: space-between;
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="radio-wrapper">
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio1">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD1</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio2">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD2</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio3">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD3</span>
  </label>
  <label class="radio-group">
    <input type="radio" name="group-1" class="radio__input" data-rad="radio4">
    <span class="radio__label">RAD4</span>
  </label>
</div>

<div class="button-wrapper">
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio1">
    RAD1
  </button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio2">
    RAD2
  </button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio3">
    RAD3
  </button>
  <button type="button" data-rad="radio4">
    RAD4
  </button>
</div>
```